# System UI won't start after tweaking Quick Setting with System Ui Tuner

Tags: system

I did a stupid mistake this afternoon. I downloaded the System UI Tuner app and tweak the status bar to only show **ONE** quick setting tile upon first swipe down (obviously wont work but idiot me still think that it is a good idea to give it a try anyway). Upon pulling the slider to 1, the System UI crash immediately and only show black screen and everything stopped working. I am desperate now and really need kind people here to help me troubleshoot this to reset and get System UI working again. I will list down some background and information below.

Device:
Asus Zenfone Max Pro M2
Just updated to Android Pie today

What is working now:
- Power Menu
- Safe Mode
- Google Assistant
- Stock Recovery
- Fastboot

What is not working (Can't find a way to make it work):
- System UI
- ADB (USB debugging was turned on but I cannot authorize my phone without System UI)
- Unlocking the screen
- Boot loader not unlocked 
- Internet (Data was not on before crash and WiFi require me to sign in)

What have I tried:
- Turn it off and on
- Boot into Safe Mode
- Wipe Cache in Recovery
- Flashing the same firmware again with recovery

Kindly request if you need more information.

Of course, the last resort is to do a factor system reset but I really wish I can keep my precious stuff in my phone... and also I've set up my phone to act as 2 factor authentication for my Google Account**s** which I might be a problem if I reset my phone.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: Given that bootloader is locked (so no access to a custom recovery) and USB Debugging not working, I see no way to solve this without factory reset. As for 2 factor authentication, if you stored recovery/backup codes as an alternative way to authenticate you don't need the phone at all. See https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en